# v-if not triggered on computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex store. on change of state preference in the vuex store. i want to rerender the DOM. i want the checkValue method to be called everytime the state preference in the vuex store changes.

index.html

```
<div id="app">
    <my-component></my-component>
    <my-other-component></my-other-component>
</div>
```

vue is initialised, and also store is imported here

my_component.js

```
Vue.component('my-component',require('./MyComponent.vue'));
import store from "./store.js"
Vue.component('my-other-component',require('./MyOtherComponent.vue'));
import store from "./store.js"

new Vue({
    el : "#app",
    data : {},
    store,
    method : {},
})
```

component where DOM needs to be change on change of the state preference in store

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div v-for="object in objects" v-if="checkValue(object)">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    methods : {
        checkValue : function(object) {
            if(this.preference) {
                // perform some logic on preference
                // logic results true or false
                // return the result
            }
        }
    },

    computed : {
        preference : function() {
            return this.$store.getters.getPreference;
        }
    }


</script>
```

Vuex store file

store.js

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state : {
    preferenceList : {components : {}},
},
getters : {
    getPreference : state => {
        return state.preferenceList;
    }
},
mutations : {
    setPreference : (state, payload) {
        state.preference['component'] = {object_id : payload.object_id}
    }
}
```

component from where the vuex store is updated on clicking in the li element.

MyOtherComponent.vue

```
<div>
    <li v-for="component in components" @click="componentClicked(object)">
    </li>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    methods : {
        componentClicked : function(object) {
            let payload = {};
            payload.object_id = object.id;
            this.$store.commit('setPreference', payload);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did you try with `v-show` instead `v-if` ?

Comment: no, i haven't. i required v-if (like behaviour) specifically

Comment: you forgot to return a value in the computed property, so it should be `return this.$store.getters.getPreference;`

Comment: 1. you need to return from the computed like @VamsiKrishna suggested.
2. why do you need `checkValue` if you only use the `preferences`, why not use the computed directly?

Comment: @fatman i remove some of the code to present the problem in brief. what i'm trying to do is, everytime the state preference changes, i need to compute some logic inside method checkValue. checkvalue returns true or false based on the logic.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna i missed the return accidentally while, shortening the code. now the problem is the checkvalue method is not called when the store state preference is updated.

Comment: @vamsi v-if is reactive , i heard. if the value inside it changes. it updates. So when computed properties are updated, is it not possible to rerender the dom

Comment: You don't use `preference` anywhere in your template, so no re-render is triggered when it changes, and without a re-render your `checkValue` function will not be called.

Comment: @FlorianHaider i'm using preference to perform some logic in  checkValue. i've updated the question. please have a look

Comment: Ok, and what does your output look like? Also can you add the part where you change your preferences?

Comment: @FlorianHaider i have updated the code. and regarding the output. i'm expecting the div block to be should based on the state preference. now the problem, checkValue is not reactive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Methods are not reactive**,

> which means they will not track changes and re-run when something
> changes. That's what you have computed for.

So it means you need to use a computed to calculate what you need, but computed does not accept parameters and you need the object, so the solution is to create another component that accepts the object as a property and then perform the logic there:

**MyOtherComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="checkValue">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    props:['object','preference']
    computed : {
        checkValue : function() {
             if(this.preference) {
               // perform some logic on preference
               // logic results true or false
               return true
             }
             
             return false
        }
    }


</script>
```

And then in the original component:

```
<template>
    <my-other-component v-for="object in objects" :object="object" :preference="preference">
        <p>hello</p>
    </my-other-component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

`v-if` should not contain a function call. Just the existence of the function will likely cause the `v-if` to always be true. `v-if` should test a variable or a computed property, and it should have a name that's a noun, not a verb ! If checkValue just proxies preference, why do you need it. Why not just `v-if="preference"` ?

Comment: i need to perform some logic in checkValue. i have updated the question.

Comment: Yep. Whether you use a noun or a verb is up to you obviously, but you need to put it in computed, and computed functions do not take arguments. You may be missing a vital distiniction. `v-if` is on the 'render' side. You have no control over when it runs. It's not a method you call. It 'reacts' when it's source data change. Computed properties are the same, so you can use a computed property in v-if. For this reason also, nouns make better names. Methods are not like that. They run when you call them, so they're usually found on the 'update' side, getting changes back into your store.

Comment: There is extremely good information supplied here in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue is your mutation: VueJS creates everything it needs for reactivity during initialization, so your `state.components` object is already initialized when you try to override it with a new object with your mutation payload, which will then not be configured for reactivity (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Try changing your mutations to:

```
mutations: {
  setPreference (state, payload) {
    Vue.set(state.preferenceList.components, 'object_id', payload.object_id);
  }
}
```